# Story about clockwork mice?

Tags: story-identification, robots, steampunk

I'm looking for a story I read about 20-30 years ago in a short story collection. It involves a man who builds a machine that looks like a large coffin, filled with clockwork gears. I can't recall if the plans for it came to him in a dream, or some other unidentified source, but he isn't sure what its purpose is. The machine makes ominous clicking noises and disgorges a bunch of little clockwork "mice" on wheels, which go on a thieving spree, stealing watches and things to bring back to the "coffin", which makes more mice. The narrator tries to capture a mouse at one point and it stabs him with a blade he recognizes as a stolen surgical scalpel. The builder and the narrator manage to destroy the coffin at the end.

I can't remember the author or title of the story or anthology. I think each story had a small black and white illustration at the beginning. I believe the stores were all older, written in the 30's or 40's. It definitely had a pulp feel to it. It was a very interesting story about self-replicating machines and I'd love to find it again.

Comment: By the way, for stories about self replicating machines, take a look at Crabs On the Island by Anatoly DNEPROV.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: Isaac Asimov Presents The Great SF Stories 3 - Book Cover] [image] [image: Isaac Asimov Presents The Golden Years of Science Fiction - 2nd Series - Book Cover]

["**The Mechanical Mice**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71451) by Maurice G. Hugi and Eric Frank Russell

According to one review, here's the gist of it:

> Dan Burman is a very rich inventor. 12 years ago, he had invented the
> "Burman Bullfrog Battery" – the greatest known power source for small
> portable devices. Now he has invented something new. Only he doesn't
> know what it's supposed to do!
>
> He seeks help from a friend, Bill, and during this discussion, Dan
> reveals that he's not the real inventor of his famous battery or the
> new device. He stole their designs from the future!
>
> His only genuine invention is a kind of crystal ball he calls
> "psychophone" – a virtual-reality time-travel machine that can take
> you to the future. And since it is impossible to go back to same time
> and place (again), a single session is all you have to learn what you
> can about anything.
>
> This is how the new machine came into existence.
>
> That is when the device – sitting in the same room – automatically
> springs into action. Arms stretch out to pick Dan's wristwatch...
>
> It's a night of sheer terror. A jeweler is robbed. There's a
> burglary at the precision instruments shop. Several cats are also
> found dead on the streets...
>
> Dan soon discovers what he has created: a robot programmed to survive
> above all else, even capable of giving birth! The brood has been
> snatching food and killing whatever comes in their way.

<sup>*~ Edited from [Variety SF](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2007/09/eric-frank-russell-maurice-g-hugis.html)*</sup>

A short excerpt from the book. How Bill reacts when he first lays eyes on the machine:

> It was a stunner. The thing was a metal box with a glossy,
> rhodium-plated surface. In general size and shape it bore a faint
> resemblance to an upended coffin, and had the same brooding, ominous
> air of a casket waiting for its owner to give up the ghost.

Another passage, this time describing the tiny thieves...

> A score of houses had been entered and four shops robbed by things
> that had the agility and furtiveness of rats — except that they
> emitted tiny ticks and buzzing noises.
>
> One was seen racing along the road by a homing railway worker. He
> tried to pick it up, lost his forefinger and thumb, stood nursing the
> stumps until an ambulance rushed him away.
>
> Rare metals and fine parts were the prey of these ticking marauders.

The story has appeared in a number of publications, including the three featured on top. Read more about it [here](http://www.strangehorizons.com/reviews/2011/04/isaac_asimov_pr.shtml) and [download](http://worldtracker.org/Library.html?url=/media/library/English%20Literature/R/Russell,%20Eric%20Frank/) a .txt file of the full story.

Answer (score 10):

The [Mechanical Mice,](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71451) by Maurice A. Hugi.
Published in Astounding Stories in January, 1941.

> ... there came a very tiny, very subtle and extremely high-pitched
> whine. Something small, metallic, glittering had shot through one of
> the rat holes, fled across the floor toward the churning monstrosity.
> A trapdoor opened and swallowed it with such swiftness that it had
> disappeared before I realized what I'd seen. The thing had been a
> cylindrical, polished object resembling the shuttle of a sewing
> machine, but about four times the size. And it had been dragging
> something also small and metallic

[image: Astounding Science Fiction, Jan 1941]

Comment: `The thing had been a cylindrical, polished object resembling the shuttle of a sewing machine, but about four times the size.`  [A early sewing machine shuttle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Singer.Model27.ShuttleThreadingDiagram.snippet.jpg) just because I didn't know.